# MongoDB: How to check is user in array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a problem. I'm creating a question to MongoDB:

```js
const team: TeamDocument = await Team.findOne({ members: payload.id, name })
```

The problem is, `members` is an array of objects:

```js
members: [{
    name: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    role: String
}]
```

So when I create ask, it showes an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got 5e88984b1478de32f43289e8
```

How can I repair this, so it will check if the members array has an object which contains an id provided in payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single query you don't even need to use `$elemMatch`, you can just use:

```
const team: TeamDocument = await Team.findOne({ "members.name": payload.id })
```

Answer (score 1):

const team: TeamDocument = await Team.findOne({ members: { id: payload.id, name:name } })

Check This Official Mongo Documentation;
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/